# How do I download Facebook playlists with youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

I use youtube-dl to download Facebook videos by passing the video URL. When Facebook plays a video, it shows a list of videos that play next. Is it possible to use youtube-dl to download all these videos automatically?

Comment: Voting to leave open. youtube-dl related questions are on-topic here, even if it's about using it on a web app.

Comment: @galacticninja Do you want me to leave this question open? How do I do that? I dont understand/know how it is done, can you help?

Comment: That comment was for the other reviewers in the [close vote review queue](http://superuser.com/review/close/549489) and for those with enough rep that might be thinking of voting to close this question. Currently this question has 4 close votes. If it gets one more vote, it will get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you can't.

The 'official' playlist on facebook is created by owner of the videos (see the playlist section at FACEBOOK/facebook/videos for example) and they can choose to share it as a link, however there is no listed format.

The videos in the same playlist might have the same prefix in URL

> **FACEBOOK**/facebook/videos/vl.515712155263726/10154651089866729/
>
> **FACEBOOK**/facebook/videos/vl.515712155263726/10154597969851729/

However, there is no offical link to such list (id vl.515712155263726).

When you view a video directly, it depends on the link, for example the same video when visited as

> **FACEBOOK**/video.php?v=10154651089866729

and

> **FACEBOOK**/facebook/videos/vl.515712155263726/10154651089866729/

will give you different next video (in what you might think as the next item in 'your' current playlist).

The source code of youtube-dl also show nothing to support facebook playlist for the time being (see https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/facebook.py).

So you are out of luck.

---

**Note:** Replace **FACEBOOK** with actual link to the site.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about that, But here is a good way. Make your Own playlist and Download all at a time.

if you are using Windows OS. Follow below steps.

1. Go to any video, and right click on that. Copy video URL.
   2.Open your notepad and paste that URL.

LIKE THIS
[image]

3. one by one paste video URL and make a playlist with in your notepad.
4. and save it with a name.
5. And run command `youtube-dl --batch-file=yourfile.txt`

Example:

i created a folder, you-dl.
And then inside you-dl , a notepad which contain list of URL. and named it downme.txt

next, cd in to that folder (you-dl) and run command `youtube-dl --batch-file=downme.txt`

Answer (score 1):

In order to download a playlist just add the next parameter

```
--yes-playlist
```

that's all, regards

Answer (score 0):

The manpage indicate :

> --playlist-start NUMBER          playlist video to start at (default is 1)
>
> --playlist-end NUMBER            playlist video to end at (default is last)

Perhaps you can do something with these. I don't know if they are only for youtube, and unfortunately I can't test for facebook.

An alternative would be to create a script to download your playlist : I made something similar for youtube playlists, you need to enter the playlist's URL though.

Creating that script (for Youtube) is easy in batch : wget to get the playlist page, then grep the vidoe links, use wc to get the links without html tags, and then supply the result to youtube-dl.

You will probably need to do something similar for facebook playlists. Is there a playlist where those video are stored ? If they are just suggestion, it might be harder to do.